Bulk add both modified or deleted files separately to index in git
I've normally used git add . which is sufficient most of the time.
But sometime I would like to separately commit deleted or both modified files after manual conflict resolution.
Though git add $file still holds good, but in case of many files, I revert to bash scripting like:
git status | grep -Po "(?<=both modified:).*" | while read x; do git add $x; done
or
git add $(git status | grep -Po "(?<=both modified:).*" | xargs)
Is there a shorter or more succinct way of doing this, or does git support any sub command to list based on file status?

How many files are we talking about when you run git add .? Dozens? Hundreds? Thousands?

deletes in 100s, both modified ~20, modified in 100s again, happens when a long running feature/refactoring gets merged once in a while.

also, except for a few, most devs are on windows and don't know bash :-|, would be good to have this in git itself.

Your use of xargs is crazy; you want git status | grep -Po "(?<=both modified:).*" | xargs git add. Using a command substitution breaks for unusual file names and obviously the lone xargs is not doing anything useful in that syntax. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

(Shouldn'e there be a space after "both modified:"?)

Isn't the simple solution to save this as a script?

yes, this I have done!
